# Simplify Query: Avoid repeated calculations in mysql

Tags: mysql

This is a query that calculated games played, Wins draws and losses for each player, as well as their points total. It seems like I'm repeating many of the same query elements. I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes might point me in a more efficient direction.

```
GAMES ->
GameID,     GameDate,       Winner
1           xxxx-xx-xx      A
2           xxxx-xx-xx      D
3           xxxx-xx-xx      B

SELECTIONS ->
GameID,     PlayerID,       Team
1           1               A
1           2               B
2           1               A
2           2               B
3           1               A
3           2               B

PLAYERS ->
PlayerID,   Name
1           John
2           Mike


QUERY ->

SELECT 
    Selections.PlayerID, 
    Players.Name, 
    COUNT(Games.Winner=Selections.Team)+COUNT(Games.Winner='D')+COUNT(Games.Winner!='D' OR Games.Winner!=Selections.Team) 
        AS GamesPlayed,
    COUNT(Games.Winner=Selections.Team) 
        AS GamesWon, 
    COUNT(Games.Winner='D') 
        AS GamesDrawn, 
    COUNT(Games.Winner!=Selections.Team OR Games.Winner!='D') 
        AS GamesLost, 
    (COUNT(Games.Winner=Selections.Team)*3)+(COUNT(Games.Winner='D')) 
        AS Points 

FROM 
    Games,Players,Selections 
WHERE 
    Games.Winner=Selections.Team 
AND 
    Players.PlayerID=Selections.PlayerID 
AND 
    Games.GameID=Selections.GameID 
GROUP BY 
    Selections.PlayerID;
```

EXPLAIN

```
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Players    | NULL       | ALL    | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                    |    2 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Selections | NULL       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                    |    6 |    16.67 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Games      | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | btest.Selections.GameID |    1 |    33.33 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@learning put up and swiftly delete a version of the following amended query which did the trick. The only thing I edited from his query is contained between `/* */`

```
SELECT 
Selections.PlayerID, 
Players.Name, 
@win:=COUNT(Games.Winner=Selections.Team) 
    AS GamesWon, 
@draw:=COUNT(Games.Winner='D') 
    AS GamesDrawn, 
@lost:=COUNT(Games.Winner!=Selections.Team OR Games.Winner!='D') 
    AS GamesLost, 
(@win*3)+@draw
    AS Points,
@win+@draw+@lost
    AS GamesPlayed 
FROM 
Games,Players,Selections  /*, (select @lost:=0,@win:=0,@draw:=0) c */
WHERE Games.Winner=Selections.Team 
AND Players.PlayerID=Selections.PlayerID 
AND Games.GameID=Selections.GameID 
GROUP BY Selections.PlayerID;
```

The bit that is commented out obviously resets the variables to 0, but it didn't work with it in.

Is there any issue with commenting this line out in a production site?